# How to use kafka connect with JDBC sink and source using python

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, kafka-python

I want to live stream from one system to another system .

I am using kafka-python and am able to live stream locally.

Figures out that connectors will handle multiple devices. Can someone suggest me a way to use connectors to implement it in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka Connect is a Java Framework, not Python.

Kafka Connect runs a REST API which you can use `urllib3` or `requests` to interact with it, not `kafka-python`

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect

Once you create a connector, you are welcome to use `kafka-python` to produce data, which the JDBC **sink** would consume, for example, or you can use `pandas` for example to write to a database, which the JDBC **source** (or Debezium) would consume

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide me some references to create a connector and how to use a JDBC sink.

Comment: I trust your ability to find that on your own. Otherwise, lookup the documentation and feel free to create a new post if you run into issues using it

Comment: @kvgrdeepika I am in the same situation, did you find a way to do that?

Comment: @Paniz The Confluent blog has several pages on the JDBC connector